# retrieving and then updating the same row in mysql with while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am reading data from local database and then doing some calculations with the information and then rewriting it back. That all works fine, but I don't know how to associate what I have done, with the correct id.

It inserts my new values at the bottom of the table, and not corresponding to the same ID. Any help will be appreciated.

id is auto incrementing.

Here is the table

```
x        y      lat     lon     id 
123     123     NewVal  NewVal  1
```

So the lat and the lon's columns are empty. When I run the PHP, it writes the correct lat and lon's back , but at the end of the database, not the corresponding X,Y.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "test") or die(mysql_error()); 
  mysql_select_db("class") or die(mysql_error()); 
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM array") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 
  require ('gPoint.php');
  $myHome =& new gPoint();  // Create an empty point
  while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
  { 
    $x = $info['x'];
    $y = $info['y'];
    $id = $info['id'];

    $myHome->setUTM( $x, $y, "39N");
    $myHome->convertTMtoLL();
    $NewLat = $myHome->Lat();  
    $NewLong = $myHome->Long();
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO array (id, lat, lon) VALUES ('$id', '$NewLat', '$NewLong')");
  }
?>
```

I am not using `$id` anywhere, beccause I am not sure how to put the two together, I have read countless tutorials and I just can't seem to figure it out.

This is the code I have,

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO array (lat, lon) VALUES ('$NewLat', '$NewLong')");
```

If I remove the id like above, it works, by adding at the bottom of the database. 
I hope anyone can help.

Comment: After calculating your new value, update your new record don't use INSERT.

Comment: Don't use deprecated methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better not use depreciated functions **Mysqli*** .Use **PDO** or **MYSQLi**

If you want to update the row..after selecting  you need to use **UPDATE** query..
and in your code  you are duplicating column **id** for inserting

Must **hash** **passwords** before storing in db

```
<?php 

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "test") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("class") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM array") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 require ('gPoint.php');
 $myHome =& new gPoint();   // Create an empty point
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
$x = $info['x'];
$y = $info['y'];
$id = $info['id'];

$myHome->setUTM( $x, $y, "39N");
$myHome->convertTMtoLL();
$NewLat = $myHome->Lat();  
$NewLong = $myHome->Long();

mysql_query("UPDATE array SET lat='$NewLAt', lon='$NewLong' WHERE id='$id'");

 }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks man, this works, all I need to do with the variables is add ''
So: '$NewLat'

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE array 
SET lat = $NewLat, long = $NewLong
WHERE id = $id
```

also consider a better name than array :)